# C# - using Monitor

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am trying to understand how Monior.Wait and Monitor.Pulse work.
As an exercise, I wrote the following program.
I was expecting m2 to be printed before m1.

Rationale : if m1 acquires the lock first, it goes to wait on obj and releases the lock. hence m1 should not be printed before m2. and if m2 acquires the lock, m2 would be printed first anyways.

But what I observe is quite different:
when I run the program normally, only m1 gets printed and it remains silent after that without terminating..perhaps the program is getting stuck in some loop somewhere. To analyze it, when I run the program in debug mode, I get the expected behavior.

Can someone please explain what is happening here? Also, what would be the right way to code this to get the intended behavior?

```
class Program
{
    static object obj = new object();
    static void m1()
    {
        lock(obj)
        {
            Monitor.Enter(obj);
            Console.WriteLine("m1");
        }
    }

    static void m2()
    {
        lock (obj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("m2");
            Monitor.Pulse(obj);

        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(m1);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(m2);
        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();                        
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that m1 is executed before m2 (or vice versa). So whether m1 or m2 acquire the lock is somewhat random, eventough it's more likely to be m1 because the thread is started first.

Comment: if m1 acquires the lock first, it goes to wait on obj and releases the lock. hence m1 should not be printed before m2. and if m2 acquires the lock, m2 would be printed first anyways...so in eithr case m2 should be printed first...what am i missing here?

Comment: there is no guarantee about the thread execution order. In your case, `m1` is scheduled to run first which calls `Monitor.Enter` (without Exit). So that `obj` is locked when `m2` is executed

Comment: Thank Khanh...that was a mistake...my intention was to call Monitor.Wait inside m1

Answer (score 2):

the `lock` statement uses `Monitor.Enter` and `Monitor.Exit` behind the scenes.

So your code

```
static void m1()
{
    lock(obj)
    {
        Monitor.Enter(obj);
        Console.WriteLine("m1");
    }
}
```

actually *acquires* the lock *twice* but only *releases it once*. Therefeore, if `m1` acquires the lock before `m2`, the lock on `obj` is never released and `m2` will wait for ever.

### Proof

(shortcut: run the code on [rextester](http://rextester.com/DAF86266))

Alter `m1` as follows:

```
static void m1()
{
    lock(obj)
    {
        Monitor.Enter(obj);
        Console.WriteLine("m1");
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine("m1 has lock on obj: ", Monitor.IsEntered(obj));
}
```

and this will be printed (well, .. only in case m1 acquires the lock first!):

> m1
>
> m1 has lock on obj:

Comment: I read that Monitor ethods have to called in the context of a lock. And the above suggests that when we do so, the thread acquires the lock twice. Isnt this a design flaw? I am sure I am wrong. Whats the missing link?

Comment: Ah! turn out there was a mistake. I intended to write Monitor.wait inside m1 and wroe Monitor.Enter by mistake

Comment: Yes `Monitor.Wait` and `Monitor.Pulse` are to be executed once you've acquired the lock either by `lock(obj)` or by executing `Monitor.Enter(obj)`.